# Always run service as NetworkService, even in interactive mode

Tags: c#

I have a service application that supports both start as service and interactive mode. The service I register is executed as the NetworkService user; the interactive mode is running as a computer administrator (normal users have no access to the program).

Now, some resources (e.g. files) are only available to the user `NetworkService`. Can I somehow tell the program to run the code as `NetworkService`, even if started by an administrator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682296/how-to-impersonate-a-wellknownsidtype

Comment: You can *restrict* permissions, if that's what you want

Answer (score 2):

> Now, some resources (e.g. files) are only available to the user NetworkService. Can I somehow tell the program to run the code as NetworkService, even if started by an administrator?

[NetworkService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272(v=vs.85).aspx) is a low privilege account. Administrator is a high privilege one. Having a situation where files are available to NS but not do admin is somewhat unusual. While is true that an admin has the right to impersonate most accounts ([`WindowsIdentity.Impersonate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate(v=vs.110).aspx), see Hans link for NS impersonate issues), I would revisit the situation and make sure this is actually necessary. It is much more likely that the files in question can, and should, be [ACL-ed](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525(v=ws.11).aspx) differently so that both NS and Local Administrators have access to the file.

Also consider splitting the application into a service component, always running as service, and a UI component that the administrator can invoke. Have the UI communicate with the service over some protocol, eg. via [LRPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272898/what-is-the-point-of-lrpc-why-would-anyone-want-to-make-remote-procedure-calls) or shared memory of even HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can change permission for file if you have Administrator rights.

Or start code as NetworkService account with help [PsExec.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911310/how-do-i-run-as-network-service)